# Multiple Submit buttons and Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, button, submit

I am using MVC 3 Razor. I have 2 submit buttons on my view the problem i m having is both submit buttons cause the validation of the model. I want to hook up individual submit buttons with specific input controls for validation.

Answer (score 3):

Add this class to your project:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ButtonClickAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[Name] != null;
    }
}
```

In view:

```
<input type="submit" value="Connect to server" name="connect" />
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ButtonClick(Name = "connect")]
public ActionResult Connect(ServerAddressModel model) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've been testing around and indeed, if you have several fields marked as `required` on your model but you want to post your model through multiple forms, every submit button will trigger validation.

An option for you would be to trigger the jQuery validation manually, so, what you could do is make those submit buttons normal buttons, ie:

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

and then attach click events to those buttons and trigger the validation in there:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#form1").validate(); // assumes a form with id="form1"

    // post the form here
});
```

You'd do the same for the other button/form.

I'd recomment taking a look a the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), by the way. Among other things, it defines a `beforeSubmit` event that you coudl use to trigger the validation.

**NOTE to all:** This is not my original answer, I've changed it *completely* after some back and forth in the comments and some testing on my side.

Comment: Well I tried this.But buttons doesn't post to respective action.

Comment: Could you let us see the code you're using? What does your view look like?

Comment: My requirement is i have few textboxes on a form.We can say 4 values are saved by Submit 1 and other 4 are saved by Submit 2. And yes you are right both submit buttons will call different actions in same controller.

Comment: @Vivek - I've just tried the example I posted, verbatim, and it works as expected: each action in the controller only receives what is supposed to receive. I've updated my answer to include controller code.

Comment: Yes it calls the actions but still both the submit buttons call the validations of other form tag.

Comment: @Vivek - I've completely changed my answer after some testing. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a blog post by Steve Sanderson which I used when playing with multiple forms on a single view.

[Partial Validation in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/)